# How to assign variables in gnu parallel?

Tags: variable-assignment, gnu-parallel

I want to assign a variable in the command that I pass to `parallel`:

```
parallel "my_variable={}_33; echo $my_variable" ::: a b c
```

The output should be:

```
# a_33
# b_33
# c_33
```

Of course, this is just a toy example. In the real example I want to do other things with that variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are *so* close to solving it yourself. You just forgot that there is a difference between " and ':

```
parallel 'my_variable={}_33; echo $my_variable' ::: a b c
```

If you are doing advanced stuff, remember that you can use bash functions:

```
doit() {
   echo Doing it for $1
   sleep 2
   echo Done with $1
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: 1 2 3
```